# Reading MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY column value into JAVA entity fails to wrong column type

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, geometry, oracle-spatial

I am using hibernate 4.1.12 and trying to have MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY column from Oracle db in my JAVA entity.

In pom.xml, I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdoapi</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In entity, I have:

```
@Column(name = "GEOMETRY", nullable = false)
private JGeometry geometry;
```

When starting the application, I get following in validation process:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/jpa-em-config.xml]: 

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: mapperPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in DB_USER1.WORK_AREA for column GEOMETRY.
Found: sdo_geometry, expected: raw(255)
```

Maybe this is not the correct way to do MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY column reading to JAVA entity? How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle10gDialect and following definitions it worked in my case.

`import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;`

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(name = "GEOMETRY", columnDefinition = "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY")
public Geometry getGeometry() {
    return this.geometry;
}
```